# How do I add a new column age, derived from birth date, to a temporary table so that I can then query that column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with birth_date. I created a temp table of this database to work with. I want to create another column, age, derived from birth date, so that I can then create age categories and get frequencies. How do I do this?

So far I've tried:

```
 alter table #DEMOGRAPHICS
  add age INT;

select BIRTH_DATE
,GETDATE() as [Today]
,DATEDIFF(YY, BIRTH_DATE,GETDATE()) - 
case 
    when month(BIRTH_DATE) > month(getdate()) or (month(BIRTH_DATE) = month(getdate()) and day(BIRTH_DATE) > day(getdate())) then 1
            else 0
            end as age
from #DEMOGRAPHICS
```

I get results back with age, but those results aren't being added to my age variable, and when I try to select top 1000 age is there, but null. I know I'm missing a step here, I'm just not sure what it is! Thanks

Comment: You've added a new column to your table but you're selecting data, not updating it. If you want to *update* rows in a table you need to `update` the table.

Comment: What do you mean by your "age variable"? There are *no* variables in the above SQL.

Answer (score 1):

When asking questions like this it's a great idea to include easily reproducible DDL/DML. This helps folks answer your question more easily.

Consider:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #BirthDates
CREATE TABLE #BirthDates (BirthDate DATE)
INSERT INTO #Birthdates (BirthDate)
SELECT TOP 300 DATEADD(DAY,-ROUND(((36500 - 7300) * rnd + 7300),0),CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))
  FROM (
        SELECT RAND(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS rnd
          FROM sys.sysobjects o
            CROSS APPLY sys.sysobjects oo
       ) a
```

This produces a temp table called #BirthDates and populates it with 300 random birthdates between 20 and 99 years old.

Calculating age can be tricky, you need to take into account what the current date is in relation to the birthdate. Just a `DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETUTCDATE())` will tell you lies for dates after today in the year.

Now, as for how to get the column you're looking for, there are two major methods to produce this. You can either add a column, and then populate the data, or you can add a computed column.

A computed column essentially adds a formula to the table, computes it, and returns the result as a column.

Computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE #BirthDates ADD AgeYears AS DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETUTCDATE())+CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETUTCDATE()),BirthDate) >= GETUTCDATE() THEN -1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT *
  FROM #BirthDates
```

| BirthDate | AgeYears |
| --- | --- |
| 1977-07-27 | 45 |
| 1927-10-05 | 95 |
| 1943-04-02 | 79 |
| 1953-01-01 | 70 |
| 2002-06-05 | 20 |
| 1984-01-24 | 39 |
| 1982-05-12 | 40 |
| 1923-11-13 | 99 |
| 1941-07-27 | 81 |
| 1978-12-11 | 44 |
| 1933-10-10 | 89 |
| ... | ... |

Create column and populate:

```
ALTER TABLE #BirthDates ADD AgeYears INT
UPDATE #BirthDates
   SET AgeYears = DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETUTCDATE())+CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETUTCDATE()),BirthDate) >= GETUTCDATE() THEN -1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT *
  FROM #BirthDates
```

| BirthDate | AgeYears |
| --- | --- |
| 1943-03-11 | 80 |
| 1968-10-27 | 54 |
| 1979-03-21 | 43 |
| 1997-01-15 | 26 |
| 1937-04-03 | 85 |
| 1962-12-15 | 60 |
| 1978-06-21 | 44 |
| 1942-03-02 | 81 |
| 2000-05-21 | 22 |
| 1940-05-06 | 82 |
| 1975-04-10 | 47 |
| ... | ... |